# Edit controls in custom control - c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I am trying to change the background color of the text box of a custom control (Custom control name is 'tc1' and text box name is 'txtb') by clicking the 'Change' button that is not in the custom control. How should I tackle this problem?

Thanks,
Wayne Scicluna

Comment: If you have control of the source for the custom control, give it a public property to change that color, since it has access to its child controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can make your `TextBox` public. to do so, go to designer of your user control, then select `Modifier` property and the set the value to public.

Now you can access it outside of your control. For example if you have an instance of your user control with name of `userControl1` and name of your text box is `txtb`:

```
userControl1.txtb.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

**Option 2:**

As another option you can create a public property and in that property get or set your textbox color.

```
public Color TextBoxBackColor
{
    get
    {
        return txtb.BackColor;
    }
    set
    {
        txtb.BackColor = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can access this property outside of your control. For example if you have an instance of your user control with name of `userControl1`:

```
userControl1.TextBoxBackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Making the TextBox public breaks encapsulation.  Better to provide a new property on the custom control.

Comment: @EricJ. In general I agree with you, but sometimes with some trade off you will prefer to expose the control.

Comment: So by exposing the control i can basically edit all the properties of that control. Am I right?

Comment: @WayneScicluna Yes, by exposing the control as a public member, you can access to all public properties and methods of that control, and option 2 is for when you want to limit access to `BackColor` property.

Comment: Ok I got it :) I just made a 7 segment display [link]http://s4.postimg.org/4vhorzp8t/lcd.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building a user control, changing the color of the textbox can be treated as a feature of the control and can be provided to clients by adding a property.

```
[Browsable(true)]  // allows you to change it in the designer
public Color TextBoxBackColor
{
    get { return txtb.BackColor; }
    set { txtb.BackColor = value; }
}
```

Comment: That public property is `Browsable` by default.